# Play-Scala Async for Dummies

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, playframework, playframework-2.0

I tried researching and understanding the async and non-blocking ability of play.

What I understand(may be wrong):
Action.async leads to Future[Result] which are placeholders of results that are yet to be received. A request comes in and a method handles it (say a database query) but as the db call is made, the thread is freed up to take another request. So how does the system not lose track of that db call as a thread is no longer with it?

Once the result is received does an available thread then pick up on that result and responds with it?

Usually when learning new concepts I'd like an animated or layman's terms type video that visually shows threads and requests.

Also isn't there waiting that has to be done on every request anyway, is it just that resources are used when that waiting is being done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can always use `Future.successful(your code)` - it will run in the same thread - but return type is as you expected. For database operations - use asynchronize jdbc drivers - or run code in new thread `Future{fetchFromDatabase()}`.